# Issue with Opening Print Dialog in Adobe Acrobat Automation

Tags: python, pdf, acrobat, pdfrw

encountering a problem while automating PDF form filling and attempting to open the print dialog in Adobe Acrobat using Python. Despite ensuring the correct installation of Adobe Acrobat and validating the code, we encountered difficulties accessing the PrintWithDialog method.

However, unable to resolve the issue with the PrintWithDialog method and encountered an AttributeError when attempting to access it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.